# Try Catch in Xquery not working in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using below code to copy documents related to specified collection from one database to another database.
In my try block I am returning to delete all the documents after successful copy. And in the catch just to print the exception .
But it gives me a syntax error which I am not able to figure out. Can someone please help me in this -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query('Test'))
let $docuri := $doc/base-uri()
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($docuri)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($docuri)
let $document-insert-options := 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
    <permissions>{$permissions}</permissions>z
    <collections>{
        <collection>{$collections}</collection>
        }
        </collections> 
  </options>
let $db-name := "Final"  
let $invoke-function-options := 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{ xdmp:database($db-name) }</database>
    <commit>auto</commit>
  </options>
return
try {
  xdmp:invoke-function(
   function(){ xdmp:document-insert($docuri, $doc, $document-insert-options)},
   $invoke-function-options
 ); 
  return xdmp:document-delete($doc)
 }
catch ($exception) {
"Problem loading file, received the following exception: ",
$exception }
```

Answer (score 2):

Michael and Rob both have good points, but there are a few more issues.

MarkLogic does complain about the extra 'z' in the $document-insert-options. Get rid of that.

MarkLogic will also complain about the fact you are passing in $doc instead of $docuri into xdmp:document-delete. So change that as well.

Last is the semi-colon bit. MarkLogic does support that, but only on top-level. Using Michael suggestion, insert and delete might happen in parallel. Using Rob's suggestion of an extra 'let $_ :=', and removing ';' will cause MarkLogic to first insert, and delete second. I think that is what you are after.

Running the following against a random database from QC ('Fab' will do), works fine on my end:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert('/test.json', object-node{"foo":"bar"}, map:entry("collections", "Test"))
;
xquery version "1.0-ml";
for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:collection-query('Test'))
let $docuri := $doc/base-uri()
let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($docuri)
let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($docuri)
let $document-insert-options := 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
    <permissions>{$permissions}</permissions>
    <collections>{
        <collection>{$collections}</collection>
        }
        </collections> 
  </options>
let $db-name := "Documents"  
let $invoke-function-options := 
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <database>{ xdmp:database($db-name) }</database>
    <commit>auto</commit>
  </options>
return
try {
  let $_ := xdmp:invoke-function(
   function(){ xdmp:document-insert($docuri, $doc, $document-insert-options)},
   $invoke-function-options
  )
  return xdmp:document-delete($docuri)
 }
catch ($exception) {
"Problem loading file, received the following exception: ",
$exception }
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @grtjn, in my query console when I executed it gave me a time-out issue, can you give some idea on why it can be :
[1.0-ml] SVC-EXTIME: xdmp:invoke-function(function() as item()*, <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>16857865358322067141</database>...</options>) -- Time limit exceeded
Stack Trace
At line 26 column 12:

Comment: Make sure source and target db are different, otherwise you cause a deadlock which will result in a timeout. Best to pick Fab as source db, it is unused.

Comment: You should use MLCP for this

Comment: MLCP doesn't really support moving files, nor does it answer OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error?

Offhand this block looks wrong:

```
let $document-insert-options := 
 <options xmlns="xdmp:document-insert">  
  <permissions>{$permissions}</permissions>z
  <collections>{
    <collection>{$collections}</collection>
    }
  </collections> 
 </options>
```

You have a `z` floating out there after `</permissions>` which could be breaking schema validation of the options node.

This also could be wrong:

```
catch ($exception) {
 "Problem loading file, received the following exception: ",
$exception }
```

You may need to explicitly return a Sequence like so:

```
catch ($exception) {
 ("Problem loading file, received the following exception: ",
$exception)}
```

This also seems odd to me:

```
try {
 xdmp:invoke-function(
  function(){ xdmp:document-insert($docuri, $doc, $document-insert- 
  options)},
  $invoke-function-options
 ); 
 return xdmp:document-delete($doc)
}
```

This breaks FLWOR by trying to use a multi-statement transaction with the `;` .

Instead try:

```
try {
 let $_ := xdmp:invoke-function(
  function(){ xdmp:document-insert($docuri, $doc, $document-insert- 
  options)},
  $invoke-function-options
 )
 return xdmp:document-delete($doc)
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error : [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_, expecting Rpar_
Stack Trace
At line 24 column 2

Answer (score 0):

XQuery doesn't have semicolon-delimited statements, nor does it have any instruction or expression that starts with the keyword "return".

```
  xdmp:invoke-function(
   function(){ xdmp:document-insert($docuri, $doc, $document-insert-options)},
   $invoke-function-options
 ); 
  return xdmp:document-delete($doc)
 }
catch ($exception) {
"Problem loading file, received the following exception: ",
$exception }
```

Replace the `"; return"` by a comma (`","`).

Marklogic may also have special rules for invoking functions with side-effects; I wouldn't know about that area.

Comment: Thanks @Michaelkay, but that gives me this error -
Stack Trace
At line 30 column 0: [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_

Comment: I don't know MarkLogic. Perhaps the [1.0-ml] means it's XQuery 1.0 in which case there is no try/catch.

Comment: @michael-kay 1.0-ml means XQuery 1.0 with MarkLogic extensions, including semi-colon (at top-level), and their flavor of try-catch.